# While loop runs indefinitely in Jmeter while using regex variable

Tags: while-loop, jmeter, infinite

([Debug sampler keeps running)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJLVd.png)I extract a variable (jobstatus) from a response body, and the variable value keeps changing.
Now i want to run this request till the variable value is either "succeeded" or "failed".
When it runs its value goes from "pending", "running" and "succeeded" or "failed".

I define the variable in "user defined variables"->jobstatus=unknown to start with the while loop, but the loop never ends.
Below is the while loop condition->

${__javaScript(("${jobstatus}" == "pending" || "${jobstatus}" == "working" || "${jobstatus}" == "unknown" || "${jobstatus}" == "running"),)}

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your expression, it should work just fine as it evidenced by the below image:

[image]

The only reason for not exiting the loop is that your regex fails to extract the status somewhere somehow, use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) or the above approach to print the `jobstatus` variable value for each iteration and also pay attention to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Also be aware that for performance reasons it's recommended to use i.e. [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy() functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) instead of JavaScript

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, for your answer. I tried changing the regex and attached debug sampler. But the while loop does not exit. See screenshot, the debug sampler keeps running.

Comment: Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance. I am new to Jmeter